# Sum vector with range-v3

Tags: c++, accumulate, range-v3

I need to sum up some vectors; that is, I want to sum the `nth` elements of every vector and make a new vector with the result. (I've already ensured that the input vectors are all the same size.) I'd like to do this with the excellent [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/) library. I've tried [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZENcLXRLHkVtJ1BT):

```cpp
// This file is a "Hello, world!" in C++ language by GCC for wandbox.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello, Wandbox!" << std::endl;

  std::vector< int > v1{ 1,1,1};
  std::vector< int> v2{1,1,1};

  auto va = ranges::view::zip( v1, v2 ) 
    | ranges::view::transform(
      [](auto&& tuple){ return ranges::accumulate( tuple, 0.0 ); }
    );

}
```

I get the error that I can't call to `ranges::accumulate` like this. I feel like this is a simple thing that I'm just not quite seeing.

Please advise

EDIT:
I ask a follow-on question here: [How to zip vector of vector with range-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819277/how-to-zip-vector-of-vector-with-range-v3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to sum over values of a tuple, instead of `accumulate`:

```
auto sum_tuple = [](auto&& tuple) { 
  return std::apply([](auto... v) { 
    return (v + ...); 
  }, tuple );
};
  
auto va = ranges::views::zip( v1, v2 ) 
        | ranges::views::transform(sum_tuple);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/BPMZW7). Shows an example with more than 2 vectors as well.

Also, note that `ranges::view` has been deprecated in favor of `ranges::views`.

Comment: Using `std::apply` works well. Why doesn't `ranges::accumulate`? (Thanks for the deprecation tip.)

Comment: `accumulate` needs the range to have `begin`, and `end`, i.e. the input must satisfy the `range` concept. `tuple` doesn't have that interface, so it doesn't satisfy that concept.

Comment: Isn't the `tuple` in my example just another `range` since it is the result of `ranges::view::zip`?

Comment: No, see for example [this](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/test/view/zip.cpp#L256). `zip` returns a `tuple`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it returned a `std::tuple`. I just used `tuple` in my example as an arbitrary name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip_with` with `std::plus<int>`. [[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/ac3czj741)

```
auto va = ranges::view::zip_with(std::plus<int>{}, v1, v2));
```