# How to zip vector of vector with range-v3

Tags: c++, vector, range-v3

(This is a follow-on to [Sum vector with range-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61785434/sum-vector-with-range-v3))

If I have two (or more) vectors, I can `zip` them together with `range-v3` like this:

```cpp
std::vector< int > v1{1,1,1};
std::vector< int > v2{2,2,2};

auto v = ranges::views::zip( v1, v2 )
  | ranges::views::transform( ... );
```

This works well, but in practice, I don't have explicit vectors, but I do have a vector of vectors. I'd like to do the following, but [it doesn't give the same result](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QquV0O7XhNgZxrXm). (In fact, I'm not sure what the result is, and I don't know how to determine what the result is!)

```cpp
std::vector< std::vector< int > > V{{1,1,1},{2,2,2}};

auto vV = ranges::views::zip( V )
  | ranges::views::transform( ... );
```

**What can I do to zip a `vector< vector >` like I did to zip a few explicit vectors?** I've tried using `join` along with `stride`, `chunk`, etc. but haven't found the magic combination.

Comment: btw, if you want to zip the fields of external `vector` it probably should not be vector but an `array` or `tuple`

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many sub-vectors there will be at compile time. I'm building up my vector (perhaps inefficiently) using `push_back` every time a new sub-vector is generated.

Comment: then there is no simple answer to your problem since zip has to know the external `vector` size in compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you don't know the size of external `vector` in compile time the only reasonable solution that remains is work around it. Instead of trying to `zip` it I would suggest going with `accumulate` on top of that as it seems more versatile in this situation.

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > > V{{1,1,1},{2,2,2}};

auto vV = ranges::accumulate(
    V,
    std::vector<ResultType>(V[0].size()),
    [](const auto& acc, const auto& next) {
        auto range = ranges::views::zip(acc, next) | ranges::views::transform(...);
        return std::vector<int>(range.begin(), range.end());
    }
)
```

EDIT:
I forgot the range has to be copied.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I like the idea, but I'm struggling to [implement it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H7P18q03TV8Pz4Wt). I'm not as familiar with `accumulate` so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @jlconlin BTW also take a look at `views::transpose`, it might suit you even more

Comment: Oh, good point. I hadn't thought of that. I love the range-v3 library, but there is just so much there that I simply don't even know what to ask. Did transpose make it into the C++20 standard?

Comment: @jlconlin don't know it honestly, you have to just check latest draft

Comment: @bartop I don't think there is a `views::transpose` in range-v3. Could you point me to it?

Answer (score 3):

`ranges::views::zip( V )` zips only one vector, not its content. (similarly to `std::make_tuple(v)` which does `std::tuple<vector<int>>`).

Issue is that vector has runtime size, so construct a `tuple` like from its contents requires some help:

```
template <std::size_t ...Is, typename T>
auto zip_vector(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v)
{
    assert(N <= v.size());
    return ranges::views::zip(v[Is]...);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
auto zip_vector(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v)
{
    return zip_vector(std::make_index_sequence<N>(), v);
}
```

And then:

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > > V{{1,1,1},{2,2,2}};

auto vV = zip_vector<2>( V )
  | ranges::views::transform( ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question you linked to, I think this particular question is an XY problem, i.e. there is no reason to involve `zip` to solve this problem, other than building upon the previous solution. While `zip` might have been a reasonable approach when the number of ranges was known at compile time, it just gets in the way when the number is only known at run-time.

So given that you have a `vector<vector<int>>`, where similar to the previous question, all the internal vectors are the same size, here's how I would write it in range-v3:

```
namespace rv = ranges::views;  

std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};

int n = v.size();
int k = v[0].size();

auto vs = v | rv::join;

auto s = rv::iota(0, n + 1) 
       | rv::transform([=](int i){
           return ranges::accumulate(
                    vs | rv::drop(i) | rv::stride(k), 0);
         });
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/-k2YA4).

Answer (score 1):

Zipping `vector<vector<T>>` is something you would want to do because it allows you to transpose these ranges.

The other answers sufficiently explain why you cant `zip` `vector<vector<T>>`.

However, you could write an explicit transpose adaptor as Eric Niebler did for his talk demonstrating range-v3

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFUXNMfaciE
- https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/example/calendar.cpp

However, this is an expensive adaptor and expensive adaptors get ignored https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/776