# How to emulate Haskell's Data.List.transpose in C++ with Range-v3?

Tags: c++, haskell, functional-programming, transpose, range-v3

These are some inputs and relative desired outputs

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> v1{"aeiou", "bcdfghjk"};
std::vector<std::string> v2{"aeiou", "bcd"};
auto w1 = v1 | wanne_be_transpose;
auto w2 = v2 | wanne_be_transpose;
// w1 = {"ab","ec","id","of","ug","h","j","k"}
// w2 = {"ab","ec","id","o","u"}
```

Honestly I have no idea how to emulate it with ranges. (Even less in the general case of `v1.size() > 2`, but my use case is inherently `v1.size() == 2`, so I'd be ok with a solution only for this case.)

Initially I thought I could `ranges::views::zip` together and then convert the pairs to inner ranges, but that wouldn't work, because `zip`'s output is as long as the shortest sequence.

Well, in Haskell there's `Data.List.transpose`:

```hs
λ> Data.List.transpose $ ["aeiou","bcdfghjk"]
["ab","ec","id","of","ug","h","j","k"]
λ> Data.List.transpose $ ["aeiou","bcd"]
["ab","ec","id","o","u"]
```

---

Coming back to this question after some time, I think I can say that `ranges::views::zip` or `ranges::views::zip_with` couldn't be of help in implementing a general `transpose` operation, because they take a variadiac number of arguments (so a number known at compile time), whereas `transpose` would have to support a number of ranges know only at run time. The reason is explained in [all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61819663/5825294) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61820340/5825294) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61824251/5825294) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61819277/5825294).

Comment: You wait to get a `zip_longest` adaptor? https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/1667

Comment: @TomHuntington, if `zip_longest` is to be implemented similarly to `zip`/`zip_with`, as in it takes a variadic number of arguments, than it could only marginally help. For instance it'd help in the case of transposing a `range<range<T>>` where the outer range length is known at compile time (my example, but not before changing `v1` and `v2` to `std::arrays<T,2>`); but it wouldn't help otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric Niebler actually implemented the truncating version of this adaptor for his talk demonstrating range-v3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFUXNMfaciE.

But it didn't make it into range-v3 https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/776

However, copy pasting from https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/example/calendar.cpp we can just do

```
std::vector<std::string> v1{ "aeiou", "bcdfghjk" };
print2D(v1 | transpose());
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vj6bbsWso

To get the non-truncating version you could modify the copy pasted code.